# python: filtering out "out of stock" products from a javascript string

Tags: javascript, python

I have pulled the all product_ids from this javascript string which are

```
['93132', '93133', '93134', '93135', '93136', '93137', '93138', '93139', '93140', '93141', '93142', '93143', '93144', '93145', '93146', '93147']
```

my next step is to filter out the sizes out of stock with either

```
"is_in_stock":false
```

or

```
"custom_status":"Out of Stock"
```

I have tried this knowing that i was not on the right path as i use this for html -

```
sizes_in_stock = []
for size in all_product_ids:
    if "Out of Stock" not in size["custom_status"]:
        size_id = size["product_id"]
        sizes_in_stock.append(size_id.split("_")[1])
```

What do i need to do to filter out the out of stock product ids and append the one in stock to my list?

Below is my code to pull the product ids from the javascript string and the javascript string itself
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

CODE to pull "product ids" -

```
product_url = "randomsite.com"
response1 = requests.get(product_url, headers=headers)
all_product_ids = re.findall('product_id":"([^"]+)', response1.text)
print(all_product_ids)
```

HTML javascript string -

```
{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93132"},"255":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93133"},"256":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93134"},"365":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93135"},"257":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93136","stockalert":""},"258":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93137","stockalert":""},"364":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93138","stockalert":""},"242":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93139","stockalert":""},"246":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93140","stockalert":""},"363":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93141","stockalert":""},"248":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93142","stockalert":""},"243":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93143","stockalert":""},"368":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93144","stockalert":""},"244":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93145","stockalert":""},"247":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93146","stockalert":""},"79":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93147","stockalert":""}});
```

Full HTML I pulled -

```
<div class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
    <script type="text/javascript">
                        try {
                            var changeConfigurableStatus = true;
                            var stStatus = new StockStatus({"255":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93004","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93004\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93004'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93004\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93004\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"256":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93005"},"365":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93006"},"257":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93007"},"258":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93008"},"364":{"is_in_stock":true,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"","product_id":"93009"},"242":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93010","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93010\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93010'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93010\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93010\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"246":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93011","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93011\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93011'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93011\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93011\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"363":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93012","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93012\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93012'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93012\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93012\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"248":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93013","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93013\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93013'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93013\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93013\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"243":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93014","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93014\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93014'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93014\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93014\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"368":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93015","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93015\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93015'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93015\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93015\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"244":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93016","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93016\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93016'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93016\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93016\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"247":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93017","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93017\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93017'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93017\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93017\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"79":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93018","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93018\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93018'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93018\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93018\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"249":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93019","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93019\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93019'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93019\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93019\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"},"245":{"is_in_stock":false,"custom_status_icon":"","custom_status":"Out of Stock","product_id":"93020","stockalert":"\r\n<div class=\"alert-stock productmail-block\">\r\n\t<label>\r\n\t\tNotify me, when the product is back in stock\t<\/label>\r\n\t<input type=\"text\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"guest_email\"\r\n\t\t   id=\"productmail_guest_email-93020\"\r\n\t\t   onKeyPress=\"return checkIt(event, 'https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', $('button-email-send-93020'))\"\r\n\t\t   class=\"input-text\"\r\n\t\t   placeholder=\"Your email address\u2026\"\r\n\t\t   size=\"30\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"product_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"93020\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"type\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"email\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"parent_id\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"92805\" \/>\r\n\t<input type=\"hidden\"\r\n\t\t   name=\"uenc\"\r\n\t\t   value=\"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlZ29vZHdpbGxvdXQuY29tL2FkaWRhcy1jb25zb3J0aXVtLXNuZWFrZXItZXhjaGFuZ2UteC1hbGlmZS14LXN0YXJjb3ctc3Rhbi1zbWl0aC13aGl0ZS1jbTgwMDA,\" \/>\r\n\t<button type=\"button\"\r\n\t\t\tid=\"button-email-send-93020\"\r\n\t\t\tclass=\"strong button btn-cart amcart-ignore\"\r\n\t\t\tonclick=\"send_alert_email('https:\/\/www.thegoodwillout.com\/productmail\/email\/stock\/', this)\"\r\n\t\t\ttitle=\"Submit\">\r\n\t\t<span>Submit<\/span>\r\n\t<\/button>\r\n<\/div>\r\n"}});
                        }
                            catch(ex){}
                    </script>
            <div class="configurable-product-option no-display">
            <div class="configurable-product-option-wrapper">
                <h2>Please select your size</h2>
                <div class="drop-select">
                    <label for="attribute139"></label>
                    <select name="super_attribute[139]"
                            id="attribute139"
                            class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                        <option>Choose an Option...</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes":{"139":{"id":"139","code":"eu_size","label":"EU ","options":[{"id":"255","label":"EU 36 2\/3 \/ US 4.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"256","label":"EU 37 1\/3 \/ US 5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["93005"]},{"id":"365","label":"EU 38 \/ US 5.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["93006"]},{"id":"257","label":"EU 38 2\/3 \/ US 6","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["93007"]},{"id":"258","label":"EU 39 1\/3 \/ US 6.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["93008"]},{"id":"364","label":"EU 40 \/ US 7","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":["93009"]},{"id":"242","label":"EU 40 2\/3 \/ US 7.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"246","label":"EU 41 1\/3 \/ US 8","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"363","label":"EU 42 \/ US 8.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"248","label":"EU 42 2\/3 \/ US 9","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"243","label":"EU 43 1\/3 \/ US 9.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"368","label":"EU 44 \/ US 10","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"244","label":"EU 44 2\/3 US 10.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"247","label":"EU 45 1\/3 \/ US 11","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"79","label":"EU 46 \/ US 11.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"249","label":"EU 46 2\/3 \/ US 12","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]},{"id":"245","label":"EU 47 1\/3 \/ US 12.5","price":"0","oldPrice":"0","products":[]}]}},"template":"\u20ac#{price}","basePrice":"149","oldPrice":"149","productId":"92805","chooseText":"Choose an Option...","taxConfig":{"includeTax":true,"showIncludeTax":true,"showBothPrices":false,"defaultTax":19,"currentTax":19,"inclTaxTitle":"Incl. Tax"}});
    </script>

    <h3>Choose size</h3>
    <div class="clearfix " data-attribute="attribute139" >
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="255">
            EU 36 2/3 / US 4.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item "
            data-value="256">
            EU 37 1/3 / US 5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item "
            data-value="365">
            EU 38 / US 5.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item "
            data-value="257">
            EU 38 2/3 / US 6        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item "
            data-value="258">
            EU 39 1/3 / US 6.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item "
            data-value="364">
            EU 40 / US 7        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="242">
            EU 40 2/3 / US 7.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="246">
            EU 41 1/3 / US 8        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="363">
            EU 42 / US 8.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="248">
            EU 42 2/3 / US 9        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="243">
            EU 43 1/3 / US 9.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="368">
            EU 44 / US 10        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="244">
            EU 44 2/3 US 10.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="247">
            EU 45 1/3 / US 11        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="79">
            EU 46 / US 11.5        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="249">
            EU 46 2/3 / US 12        </div>
                    <div class="attribute-item disabled"
            data-value="245">
            EU 47 1/3 / US 12.5        </div>
        </div>

                <div id="stock-alert-notification">
    <span>Desired size not in stock?</span>
</div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var DateOption = Class.create({

    getDaysInMonth: function(month, year)
    {
        var curDate = new Date();
        if (!month) {
            month = curDate.getMonth();
        }
        if (2 == month && !year) { // leap year assumption for unknown year
            return 29;
        }
        if (!year) {
            year = curDate.getFullYear();
        }
        return 32 - new Date(year, month - 1, 32).getDate();
    },

    reloadMonth: function(event)
    {
        var selectEl = event.findElement();
        var idParts = selectEl.id.split("_");
        if (idParts.length != 3) {
            return false;
        }
        var optionIdPrefix = idParts[0] + "_" + idParts[1];
        var month = parseInt($(optionIdPrefix + "_month").value);
        var year = parseInt($(optionIdPrefix + "_year").value);
        var dayEl = $(optionIdPrefix + "_day");

        var days = this.getDaysInMonth(month, year);

        //remove days
        for (var i = dayEl.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (dayEl.options[i].value > days) {
                dayEl.remove(dayEl.options[i].index);
            }
        }

        // add days
        var lastDay = parseInt(dayEl.options[dayEl.options.length-1].value);
        for (i = lastDay + 1; i <= days; i++) {
            this.addOption(dayEl, i, i);
        }
    },

    addOption: function(select, text, value)
    {
        var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
        option.value = value;
        option.text = text;

        if (select.options.add) {
            select.options.add(option);
        } else {
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
});
dateOption = new DateOption();
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: the first element in HTML HS string response does not have a KEY ?

Comment: Try using [```ast.literal_eval```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the string into dictionaries first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited)
Given the output, that's HTML with some JSON inside. You might use regular expressions to get the JSON out, then parse it to native Python objects.

Something like:

```
    import re
    import json

    json_text = None
    lines=result1.text.split('\n')
    r = re.compile('new StockStatus\(({.*})\);$')
    for l in lines:
        m = r.search(l)
        if m:
            json_text = m.group(1)
            break

    items = json.loads(json_text).values()
    filtered_items = [x['product_id'] for x in items if x.get('is_in_stock') and x.get('custom_status') != 'Out of Stock']
    print filtered_items
```

Comment: thank you uri appreciate the time you did on my question.

Answer (score 0):

use `json.loads` to convert it to object

```
import json

all_product_ids = json.loads(jsonString)
sizes_in_stock = []
for size in all_product_ids:
    if "Out of Stock" not in all_product_ids[size]["custom_status"]:
        size_id = all_product_ids[size]["product_id"]
        #size_id = size_id.split("_")[1] # "93147" what to split?
        sizes_in_stock.append(size_id)

print sizes_in_stock
# ['93135', '93134', '93132', '93133']
```